# Why does curl error after version update?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, php-curl

After update version of ci 3.1.1 & php 7.3 there is a error in curl call using rest library in codeingiter

error like : **45bind failed with errno 10014: Bad argument**

i make a manual call using curl working perfect but using curl library there is a error like above. any solutions?

Comment: Can U share your code?

Comment: i managed by curl library